# How can i make a TimeStamp with milliseconds?

Tags: java, android

```
String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator  + "Picture" + timeStamp +     ".jpg";
```

How can i make a TimeStamp with milliseconds?? I need to make every picture name different so they don't overwrite each other.

Comment: How are you currently getting the timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
```